# Zurb foundation tobar hover only on desktop but still click on tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

ok this is my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epbePZ

```
 <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
          <a href="#">Programs</a>
          <ul class="dropdown m-menu"><li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="javascript:void(0)">Back</a></h5></li><li class="parent-link show-for-small-only"><a class="parent-link js-generated" href="#">Programs</a></li>
            <li>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-4 column">
                  <h3>Undergraduate</h3>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Admissions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Academics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fields of Study</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fees and Finance</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Useful Contacts</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!--end of .column-->
                <div class="medium-4 column">
                  <h3>Graduate</h3>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Admissions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Academics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fields of Study</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fees and Finance</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!--end of .column-->
                <div class="medium-4 column">
                  <h3>Online Learning</h3>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Why e-learning?</a>
                    </li><li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Studies</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Date &amp; Deadlines</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fees and Finance</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!--end of .column-->
              </div><!--end of .row-->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-4 column">
                  <h3>Read</h3>
                  <a href="#" class="intro">
                    <i class="icon-play"></i>
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/280?image=532">
                  </a>
                </div><!--end of .column-->
                <div class="medium-4 column">
                  <h3>Build</h3>
                  <a href="#" class="intro">
                    <i class="icon-play"></i>
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/280?image=534">
                  </a>
                </div><!--end of .column-->
                <div class="medium-4 column">
                  <h3>Enjoy</h3>
                  <a href="#" class="intro">
                    <i class="icon-play"></i>
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/280?image=452">
                  </a>
                </div><!--end of .column-->
              </div><!--end of .row-->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

the drop down works ok and but when you click on the dropdown and hover over another they overlap i just want it to hover on desk top and click on tablet. is it to do with a not-click element ?

think that makes sense any help would greatly appreciated

Thanks
dan

Answer (score 0):

It can be kind of confusing, but I followed some of the docs as I'm sure you did here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

I put the `data-options` in the `a` of the dropdown similar to the below code.

```
    <li class="has-dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-options="is_hover:true; hover_timeout:0" data-dropdown="hover1">Programs</a>
      <ul id="hover1" class="dropdown m-menu" data-dropdown-content>
        <li>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-4 column">
              <h3>Undergraduate</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Admissions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Academics</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fields of Study</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fees and Finance</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Useful Contacts</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--end of .column-->
            <div class="medium-4 column">
              <h3>Graduate</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Admissions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Academics</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fields of Study</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fees and Finance</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--end of .column-->
            <div class="medium-4 column">
              <h3>Online Learning</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Why e-learning?</a
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Studies</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Date & Deadlines</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Fees and Finance</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="icon-circle-right"></i>Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--end of .column-->
          </div><!--end of .row-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-4 column">
              <h3>Read</h3>
              <a href="#" class="intro">
                <i class="icon-play"></i>
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/280?image=532" />
              </a>
            </div><!--end of .column-->
            <div class="medium-4 column">
              <h3>Build</h3>
              <a href="#" class="intro">
                <i class="icon-play"></i>
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/280?image=534" />
              </a>
            </div><!--end of .column-->
            <div class="medium-4 column">
              <h3>Enjoy</h3>
              <a href="#" class="intro">
                <i class="icon-play"></i>
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/280?image=452" />
              </a>
            </div><!--end of .column-->
          </div><!--end of .row-->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

If you put this similar convention on all your dropdown items including the `data-dropdown-content` attribute on the `ul` tags containing your dropdown content, you should be good to get a standard hover effect on them without the overlapping.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for this works like a charm on desktop, however on tablet im getting a simlar issue when i click one dropdown it wont close the other ones just overlaps them, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue it seems. My only thought is that maybe some of your custom Javascript is interfering or overriding the Foundation scripts attempting to hide the dropdown after another is clicked. If simplifying that doesn't work, you may need to write some additional Javascript to bind the onTouch event to manually close them. Good luck to you!